# Speech recognition with PhoneGap or Sencha

Tags: mobile, speech-recognition

I'm planning to use Sencha 2.0 as my platform for mobile apps development. And I'm planning to use Speech recognition in the app - is there a Speech Recognition API that will work well across iOS and Android platforms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, the answer is no.

Most speech recognition apps on smartphones do the speech processing on servers. Google provides built in speech recognition through the [Speech Input API for Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html). This api on the client will record the users speech, send it to a Google server for analysis, and return the recognized text. Google provides this service for Android apps for free. Some folks have reverse engineered the Speech recognition service Google provides for [Chrome](http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/) if you want an idea of how it works.

Today, Apple's iOS does not include a comparable API. There is hope that in the future they will expose an API to leverage the Siri servers for 3rd party apps, but today they do not. So, to build speech enabled apps for the iPhone requires deploying or contracting speech recognition services. [Nuance](http://www.nuance.com/for-developers/dragon-mobile-sdk/index.htm), [iSpeech](http://www.ispeech.org/developers), and others offer iOS SDKs for speech recognition in mobile apps.

Others on StackOverflow have discussed using [PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx) as a client based speech recognition engine, but I have no experience with that.

Though I guess it is possible for Sencha or PhoneGap to provide a common API for speech recognition, since there is no standard or free speech recognition solution for iPhone, it seems unlikely that these frameworks would be able to solve this complex problem. Perhaps if Apple exposes Siri in their SDK, a client framework could provide a common solution for iPhone and Android.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Meanwhile, I've also been looking at Nuance. And particularly interested in their Client side API.

Comment: iSpeech looks promising. Or at least has a nice website and low prices (free for mobile apps, cheap for websites)

Comment: Nuance is free for development and demos. You just have to pay for high volume use - http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home.