# Can PhoneGap access the iPhone's voice recognition software?

Tags: iphone, cordova, voice-recognition

Not just access the microphone-- I mean the iPhone's ability to translate spoken language to text. Like what Siri uses, but minus the whole "understanding natural language" part. Just the figuring out literally word-for-word what was said. Voice recognition. Is that an accessible functionality?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the voice recognition? AFAIK the voice feature is still usable on any textbox/view.

Comment: I just want users to be able to give text input with their voice, if they wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write a **PhoneGap plugin** which runs Objective-C code to do the voice recognition.

Please refer the below links

[phonegap-speech-recognition-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120877/phonegap-speech-recognition-sdk)

[First-test-of-PhoneGap-Plugins](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/12/First-test-of-PhoneGap-Plugins)

[speech-recognition-with-phonegap-or-sencha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013319/speech-recognition-with-phonegap-or-sencha)